# PHP import CSV with umlauts

Tags: php, csv, character-encoding

I have a website where my user can upload a file. This file contains some German umlauts (as ö and ä) and is latin_1 encoded. Now I need to convert this file to UTF-8 because this charset is used by my database.

I use the following code:

```
        $csvFile = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');
        //parse data from csv file line by line
        while(($line = fgetcsv($csvFile, 0, "\t")) !== FALSE){
                $dbupload->query("INSERT INTO db (a, b, c) 
                             VALUES ('".$line[0]."', '".$line[3]."', '".$line[1]."')");
            }
        }

        //close opened csv file
        fclose($csvFile);
```

If I use this code and import a latin_1 file, PHP skips every line containing an umlaut.

What can I do?

PS: The file is directly passed from the frontend (the page the user uses) to this file which processes it.

Comment: utf-8 is your friend

Comment: Simply open the CSV, and save it in UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, do not pass data from user's upload directly to database! Please use [pdo statements](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Also make sure which encoding you have in the file. In example i have use [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) but i can missunderstand you.

Here is a part of my code that using [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php):

```
$csvFile = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');

//parse data from csv file line by line
while(($line = fgetcsv($csvFile, 0, "\t")) !== false) {
    foreach ($line as $key => $value) {
        $line[$key] = iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $value); //but be sure in your charset name
    }
    //do not pass data from user upload directly to database!
    //use pdo or addslashes at least
    $dbupload->query("INSERT INTO db (a, b, c) VALUES ('".addslashes($line[0])."', '".addslashes($line[3])."', '".addslashes($line[1])."')");
}

//close opened csv file
fclose($csvFile);
```

Please see iconv documentation for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you check this list [here](http://www.utf8-zeichentabelle.de/), you will see that die Umlaute are included, which mentioned, that they can be en- and decoded.
As it was mentioned, saving the file with and in an UTF-8 Encoding, will do the trick. Otherwise the file will not do it automatically, that is why you have the problem.